# Having an issue with structs and the program not saving inputs. I am inexperienced

Tags: c

The compiler doesn't come up with any errors...It is supposed to be a basic phonebook with 5 slots for people. For some reason everything seems to work but it doesn't save the information. What did I do wrong?

```
typedef struct contact{
  char fname[10];
  char lname[10];
  int pnumber;
};

struct contact p1;
struct contact p2;
struct contact p3;
struct contact p4;
struct contact p5;

int go =0;

int phonebook(struct contact person,int use);

int main(){
 while(go == 0){
   int contact;
   int choice;
   int location;

   printf("first what position in your contacts would you like to change?(1-5)\n");

   scanf("%d",&location);

   printf("what would you like to do?\n1. add a contact\n2. change a contact\n3. print  a 

   contact\n4. Quit\n");

   scanf("%d",&choice);

   switch(location){
    case 1:
     phonebook(p1,choice);
     break;
    case 2:
     phonebook(p2,choice);
     break;
    case 3:
     phonebook(p3,choice);
     break;
    case 4:
     phonebook(p4,choice);
     break;         
    case 5:
     phonebook(p5,choice);
     break;
    default:
     printf("that was not a valid option\n");
  } 
 }

 system("PAUSE");
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int phonebook(struct contact person,int use){
  switch(use){
   case 1:
    if(person.pnumber>0){ 
      printf("you already have a contact there\n");
    }
    else{
      printf("What is the contact's first name?\n"); 
      scanf("%s", &person.fname);
      printf("\nWhat is the contact's last name?\n");
      scanf("%s", &person.lname);
      printf("\nWhat is the contact's phone number?\n");
      scanf("%d", &person.pnumber);
    }
   break;
  case 2:
   if(person.pnumber == 0)
     printf("No contact is saved in this position\n");
   else{
     printf("What is the contact's first name?\n"); 
     scanf("%s", &person.fname);
     printf("\nWhat is the contact's last name?\n");
     scanf("%s", &person.lname);
     printf("\nWhat is the contact's phone number?\n");
     scanf("%d", &person.pnumber);
   }
  break;     
 case 3:
  printf("\nName:%s\n%s \nNumber:%d \n",&person.fname,&person.lname,&person.pnumber);
  break;
 case 4:
  go = 1;
  break;
 default:
  printf("that wasn't an option. Please pick a valid option next time.\n");
 }

}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could narrow down the problem and reformat your code.  Most people don't want to parse everything you have.

Comment: If you want us to read all your code, can you please at least indent it properly. To help the reader you should also only keep or at least stress the relevant part of the code.

Comment: 1. What do you mean that it "does not save the information"? Please give an example of running your program and explain how the output differs from what you expect. 2. Please format your code with appropriate indentation and whitespace.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure what was going wrong so I posted everything. The program I use has them all indented properly but the copy paste didn't get that, I do apologize. As far a not saving the information goes I do believe the answers posted were correct...still working on how to fix it though.

Comment: re: "copy paste didn't get that" That's fine, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't reformat your code before you post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a simple problem: the C language uses "call by value", so your `phonebook()` function gets a copy of the struct.  Then the `phonebook()` function changes the copy, but the changes aren't saved anywhere.

The way you fix this: you have to make your `phonebook()` function take a *pointer* to a struct, and then it can use the pointer to modify the struct.

```
int phonebook(struct contact *pcontact, int use)
{
    // ... stuff omitted ...

    printf("What is the contact's first name?\n");
    scanf("%s", pcontact->fname);  // "fname" works as a pointer

    printf("\nWhat is the contact's phone number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &pcontact->pnumber);  // must take address of integer "pnumber"

// ... rest of phonebook() omitted ...

// example of calling phonebook():
case 1:
    phonebook(&p1, choice);
```

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-tutor.html#pointers

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Pointers point to specific values of the struct, right? so would I have to send a different pointer for each value?

Comment: @user2592484 You can point to an entire struct. The whole struct will be in a contiguous section of memory and in fact `C` has the [-> operator](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#pointer_to_member)  just for accessing members of a struct through a pointer to the struct.

Comment: You need to pass the pointer to a specific struct that you want the `phonebook()` function to modify.  I added an example showing the call.

Comment: Also, in a real program, you will probably have your struct members in an array.  I imagine that your next assignment will be to rewrite this one to use an array of struct values instead of declaring five different struct variables.

Comment: You are enormously helpful. I thought it was all fixed until it crashed after I entered the phone number...I might get it to work eventually!

Comment: I narrowed it down to one line specifically that everything before that line works, nothing after it does...and the line itself seems to work but when I hit enter crashes. Does the line scanf("%d", pcontact->pnumber); seem to have anything wrong with it?

Comment: Doesn't scanf want the address of pnumber - a pointer to int here?

Comment: When you call `scanf()` you need to pass in a pointer.  Look at my code samples.  `pcontact->fname` has the comment that "fname works as a pointer", and `&pcontact->pnumber` has the comment "must take address of integer pnumber".  `fname` is an array of `char`, and the name of an array, by itself, works as a pointer to the first thing in the array.  `pnumber` is an integer, and you *must* explicitly take the address of an integer variable to get a pointer to it.  Check out that link I put at the end of my answer; it discusses the basics of pointers in C.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `person` by value, not by reference, so `phonebook` is making changes to a copy of the contact struct.

Try

```
int phonebook(struct contact *person,int use);
```

Comment: C does not have references.

Comment: @wildplasser [Yes, it does.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science))

Comment: Maybe you should ask the compiler, but the above function declaration is a syntax error in C.

Comment: C language doesn't have pass-by-reference concept.

Comment: @Paulpro, maybe you are thinking of C++?  In C, you have to do references yourself, using explicit pointers.  The C compiler won't like the syntax in the example shown.

Comment: @steveha Nope, I'm thinking of `C`. A pointer is a reference. `C` doesn't allow pass-by-reference, hence I upvoted Mahesh's comment, but it does allot you to pass a reference by value.

Comment: @Paulpro, this answer has been corrected; but when you posted your first comment, this answer had C++ syntax for a "reference".  The corrected answer now has C syntax for a "pointer" (also valid in C++ of course).  Most people would agree that a language that forces you to explicitly declare a pointer and explicitly dereference that pointer does not "have references", which is why I asked if you were thinking of C++.  It is certainly true that explicitly using pointers to allow changing values is "pass[ing] a reference by value" but C has no equivalent of a "reference" from C++.